# How to add search path into "which"?

Tags: linux, path, centos

When I type `which testWhich`, where `testWhich` is an executable file under `~/test` folder, I see

`/usr/bin/which: no testWhich in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin)`.

I'd like know how to add `~/test` folder into the search path of `which` so that I can execute `testWhich` anywhere in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the manpage of which:

> it does this by searching the PATH for executable files matching the names of the  arguments.

you should added ~/test to your PATH environment variables. for doing it on bash shell, using the following command:

> export PATH=~/test:$PATH

Comment: Thank you for answering my question :-)